# C++ code compiles and executes correctly however VSCode displays error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

The code below compiles and runs as expected however, VSCode is showing IntelliSense errors.
"expected expression [32, 49]" and red squiggly lines under the lambda capture. In my VSCode config files, cppStandard is set to "c++17". What can I do to remove these warnings?

[vscode intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFqf9.png)

[squiggly line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD2QC.png)

```
void solve() {
    int n, val;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    vector<int> e, o;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &val);
        if (val % 2 == 0) e.push_back(val);
        else o.push_back(val);
    };

    if (e.size() % 2 == 0 && o.size() % 2 == 0) {
        printf("YES\n");
        return;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++) {
        bool found = any_of(o.begin(), o.end(), [e, i](int v) -> bool {
            return v == e[i]+1 || v == e[i]-1; });
        if (found) {
            printf("YES\n");
            return;
        };
    };

    printf("NO\n");
    
};
```

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot of the error, please?

Comment: Why are you using `printf` and `scanf` in a C++ program? What resource are you using to learn C++? Don't use so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites to learn programming or programming languages, such sites are *not* learning or teaching resources and can for beginners be actively harmful to the learning process.

Comment: Fwiw, I honestly see zero sense in capturing either `e` or `i` by *value* in this case. Not really sure why you're even doing it.

Comment: @ksohan they've been added now

Comment: @WhozCraig if i don't capture e and i then it wouldn't actually compile

Comment: Um.. what ?? You mean [this won't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/1o95efeKa) ???

Comment: It's not the capture itself that @WhozCraig is talking about, it's capturing *by value* instead of *by reference*. When you capture by value you make a *copy* of the vector. Which could be rather inefficient. If you capture by reference instead then no copies are made.

Comment: So is your your question: _Why do I need to capture `e` and `i` for my lambda?_

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh yes my bad

Comment: @Jabberwocky my question is why is vscode showing "expected expression warning" even though the code compiles

Comment: @mmattyboi those squiggly lines are not always correct. Believe the compiler, not the editor.

Comment: According to [this old issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/628) the "expected expression" is most likely because of other plugins enabled in VSCode. Start disabling plugins and see when the error disappears. (I found this doing a search for `vscode c++ intellisense lambda expected expression`, please remember to do some searching first before posting questions in the future).

Comment: @Jabberwocky thats true. but i hope there is a way to adjust it because it is slightly confusing to see errors like this

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the post did not specify which c++ extension caused the issue. additionally, previous posts on forums relate to the compiler failing to build their code whereas in my case it is simply the editor showing an error that shouldnt be there

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/628#issuecomment-293311497) (on the previously linked issue) is from one of the developers of the VSCode C++ plugin at Microsoft, and he says the error is not from their plugin. So that's why you should disable *all* your plugins, one by one, until the problem disappears. Then you know which plugin (or extension as they call it) is the culprit.

Comment: How it usually goes: IntelliSense: "You made a typo there." Me: "I know, I'll fix that later." IntelliSense: "Do it now. I will keep reminding you until you fix it." Me: Don't bother. If I forget, the compiler will yell at me." IntelliSense: "And that thing you wrote now is wrong, too. I think. Perhaps." Me: "I don't care, it's just a draft." IntelliSense: "BUT YOU MUST FIX IT NOW! LOOK AT ME I NEED YOUR ATTENTION ALL THE TIME!" Me: "*plonk*". Sigh of relief.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++11, while you set your vscode to C++17?